# Crystal Web Viewer ActiveX will not install on IE8 and Windows 7

Tags: crystal-reports, internet-explorer-8, activex

Windows 7 + IE8 + Crystal Report 11 Report + web viewer ActiveX will not install. ActiveX prompt appears, the UAC is approved to install, the page then refreshes and the process starts over 4 times until I get an a script warning.

Has anyone else come across this issue or a possible solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A workaround is to download the ActiveXViewer.cab file, extract the contents to a folder in C:\ on the machine used to view the reports and register the DLLs manually.

The URL for the cabinet file for Crystal 11 (XI Release 1) looks something like this:
http://yourwebsitewherecrystalisinstalled/crystalreportviewers11/ActiveXControls/ActiveXViewer.cab

Once you have extacted the contents to a folder on your hard drive, register the DLLs.
You only need to register the DLLs that are not provided by the OS.
For Crystal 11 (XI Release 1) the commands to register the DLLs are:

REGSVR32 /S CRVIEWER.DLL

REGSVR32 /S REPORTPARAMETERDIALOG.DLL

REGSVR32 /S SVIEWHLP.DLL

REGSVR32 /S SWEBRS.DLL

Update - to install the Crystal Web Viewer ActiveX from a web site in IE8 on Windows 7, try:

1) Login to a local administrator account (but not the built-in local administrator)

2) Add the site to your trusted sites list

3) Enable UAC at the default level - reboot if needed

4) Launch IE8, browse the site and click through the prompts

Once the control is installed, it can be run by non-administrators on the same machine and UAC can be disabled / reduced.

Comment: And if the website where crystal is installed is locked in a bank of america data center somewhere in the world? I don't have access to their web servers but our users need this installed to access the reports on their site. I don't work for bank of america.

Answer (score 1):

**Situation 1:** Prompting Crystal Reports Add-on

- While loading reports through your application, If Crystal Reports
  Active X is not present;
- it will prompt you for the installation
- Unblock any pop-up if required
- Once it is being installed, the reports will load

**Situation 2:**

- Run the Active X Viewer 11.5 Set up
- In case the report is not loaded, run the Active X Viewer 11.5 Set up
  Situation 3: Manually Registering DLL   In case report is still not
  loaded with situation 1 & 2,
- Run the Active X Viewer 11.5 Setup
- Register the following DLLs manually as follows:

> o REGSVR32 \ path \ CRVIEWER.DLL
>       o REGSVR32\ path \ REPORTPARAMETERDIALOG.DLL
>       o REGSVR32 \ path \ SVIEWHLP.DLL
>       o REGSVR32 \ path \ SWEBRS.DLL

**Note:**
• Internet Explorer 7 or 8 should be installed on those machines
• You should be logged in as administrator

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone is looking for a solution for windows 7: run secpol.msc. Under Local Policies, click on the Security Options. To the right are all the policies, look for User Account Control towards the bottom. You need to Enable "Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode". Enable "Admin Approval Mode for the Built-In Administrator Account". You will need a reboot for the policy to take. Rerun the active prompt and it should install whithout a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the answer provided at the below link by Rocky did the trick. Copying the solution here:

"What I ended up doing was right-clicking on IE9 and Run as administrator > Internet Options > Advanced > (scroll down to the security section) check the 'Allow software to run or install even if the signature is invalid'. Close the browser, re-open (Run as administrator again) and run your report."

This allowed me to install the activeX. I reenabled security, restarted the browser, and viewing reports still works.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/cannot-run-report-because-activexviewercab-is/90a2c5f7-77a5-4ed3-9478-1a396e5e5e6c?msgId=db0a1d21-2dcd-443e-82fa-1a9b5fcbaad2

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you add the urls into your trusted sites and or your Intranet sites through IE 8's Internet Options tabs...that made a huge difference to me.